# Skype with bluetooth headset on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth, skype

I have AKG K830BT bluetooth headset which works perfectly with my MacBook Pro (Mac OS X 10.6.7). The only problem is while using Skype. It looks like Skype wants to use my built-it speakers disregarding the BT headset which is already successfully paired. So the result is that I can head system signals (e.g. a sound assigned to the activity of closing a Skype conversation window) in my headset but not the conversation.

Is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Skype's Audio/Video preferences you need to see the microphone and speaker source to the BlueTooth headset in order for Skype to use them. So CMD-` to open Skype preferences, click the 'Audio/Video' tab icon and then check your settings.

In my own Skype install you can see I have to set it to use my Plantronics .520 headset if I want to use that for input or output:

[image: Skype Audio/Video Preferences]